# Can multiple threads in same container run parallel using multiple cores at the same time when I use under 1000m cpu requests in kubernetes?

Tags: multithreading, kubernetes, cpu, multicore, cgroups

When I googled, there were some answers saying that in kubernetes, 100ms cpu means that you are going to use 1/10 time of one cpu core, and 2300ms cpu means that you are going to use 2 cores fully and 3/10 time of another cpu core. Is it correct?

I just wonder if multiple threads can run in parallel on multiple cores at the same time when using under 1000ms cpu requests in kubernetes.

Comment: These articles might be helpful: https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-cpu-time-9eff74d3161b   https://opensource.com/article/19/2/fair-scheduling-linux

Comment: @Sam Did you very find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding first part, it's true that you can use part of CPU resource to run some tasks.
In [Kubernetes documentation - Managing Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) you can find information that you can specify minimal resources requirements - `requests` to run pod and `limits` which cannot be exceeded.

It's well described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits)

> Requests and limits are the mechanisms Kubernetes uses to control resources such as CPU and memory. Requests are what the container is guaranteed to get. If a container requests a resource, Kubernetes will only schedule it on a node that can give it that resource. Limits, on the other hand, make sure a container never goes above a certain value. The container is only allowed to go up to the limit, and then it is restricted.

**CPU Requests/Limits:**

> CPU resources are defined in millicores. If your container needs two full cores to run, you would put the value `2000m`. If your container only needs ¼ of a core, you would put a value of `250m`.
> One thing to keep in mind about CPU requests is that if you put in a value larger than the core count of your biggest node, your pod will never be scheduled.

**Regarding second part, you can use multiple threads in parallel.** Good example of this is [Kubernetes Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

> A simple case is to create one Job object in order to reliably run one Pod to completion. The Job object will start a new Pod if the first Pod fails or is deleted (for example due to a node hardware failure or a node reboot).
> You can also use a Job to run multiple Pods in parallel.

Especially part about [Parallel execution for Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs)

You can also check [Parallel Processing using Expansions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/) to run multiple `Jobs` based on a common template. **You can use this approach to process batches of work in parallel.** In this documentation you can find example with description how it works.